Pie charts on leaflet map
I have a very simple dataset.
df <- data.frame(lat = c(47.4979, 47.4970),
                 lon = c(19.0402, 19.0408),
                 fel = c(60, 30),
                 le = c(40, 70))

I want to visualize it on a leaflet map, with pie charts. The addMinicharts function puts it on but my viewer freezes and I can never zoom in or out. Also, the customizability of the charts is very limited. there really isn't any easy way to put a pie chart to certain coordinates, while adding a circle marker with size based on a value is so straightforward?

Use the leaflet.minicharts package...
df$total<-df$fel+df$le

basemap<-leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")
basemap

colors <- c("darkgreen", "#cccc11")

basemap %>%
  addMinicharts(
    df$lon, df$lat,
    type = "pie",
    chartdata = df[, c("fel", "le")], 
    
    colorPalette = colors, 
    width = 60 * sqrt(df$total) / sqrt(max(df$total)), transitionTime = 0
  )


yeah, But it freezes and cannot zoom in or out, and also the charts are uncustomizable
